# How to test a UWP App running on a windows computer for zoom functionality

Tags: windows, xamarin, uwp

I am sorry but I might have to ask a really silly question as I have been googling for quite some time and can't seem to find the answer for my issue. I am currently developing a Xamarin cross platform application and my application has a zoom functionality implemented. However, unlike real tablets and phones which we can use our fingers to do the zooming, I am unsure as to how to test zooming on a windows computer for a UWP application installed using my mouse and keyboard.

Any kind soul willing to give me some advice on how to zoom using mouse and keyboard on a windows computer for a UWP app?

Comment: Use mouse wheel or ctrl + mouse wheel

Comment: If you are using laptop , simply use your touchpad mouse

Answer (score 1):

- Holding the Ctrl key down while scrolling the mouse scroll wheel
- Holding the Ctrl key down (with the Shift key, if no numeric keypad is available) and pressing the plus (+) or minus (-)

> Both optical zoom and resizing interactions are performed through the pinch and stretch gestures (moving fingers farther apart zooms in and moving them closer together zooms out), or by **holding the Ctrl key down while scrolling the mouse scroll wheel**, or by **holding the Ctrl key down (with the Shift key, if no numeric keypad is available) and pressing the plus (+) or minus (-) key**.

Ref: [UWP Optical zoom and resizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/guidelines-for-optical-zoom)

Comment: tried that but it didnt do anything. Any idea if this would work with the xamarin forms pinch gesture because it doesn't seem to trigger my pinch gesture at all?

Comment: I did a sample project and it works on android tablet when i pinch and zoom with my fingers but on uwp on windows computer using the mouse and keyboard I can never get it to zoom even if i hold the control key down or use the control shift plus to zoom